# Show: the subspace of compact operators is $\Lambda$-invariant

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $A \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ be fixed. Define $\Lambda: \mathcal{L}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(X)$ by $ \Lambda (T)=A^{*}T+TA,\;T\in \mathcal{L}(X)$.

Show: the subspace of compact operators is $\Lambda$-invariant:$$\left\{ \Lambda(T) | T \in \mathcal{C}(X)  \right\} \subset  \mathcal{C}(X).$$

My thought:

If $T$ is compact, then so are $A^{*}T$ and $TA$ and sum of compact operators is also compact. So, we can conclude that $A^{*}T+TA$ is compact.

Am I correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Maybe you need to prove that the sum of two compact operators and the composition of a compact operator with a continuous operator is again compact, maybe that was already proved and can be used. But the argument is correct even if its parts have not yet been proved (then it would be incomplete, however).

Comment: @daniel thank you for your comments. I am able to prove the composition one but I do not know how to prove the sum. Would you please show me about this? Thank you so much.

Comment: So the parts haven't been proved yet? I'm mildly surprised by that. But well. What definition or characterisation of compact operators are you most comfortable with?

Comment: @daniel by compactness: Given that $X$ is an inner product space then the linear transformation $T:X \rightarrow X$ is compact if all bounded sequence ${x_n}$ is contained in $X$, then ${Tx_n}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Okay. So suppose you have two compact operators, say $K$ and $L$. Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence. By compactness of $K$, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $Kx_{n_k}$ converges. Do yo see how it continues?

Comment: @daniel for example, $Kx_{n_k}$ has limit $k$ and and $Lx_{n_k}$ has limit $l$ and probe that $(K+L)x_{n_k}$ has limit $k+l$?

Comment: Almost. We only know that $Kx_{n_k}$ converges, not that $Lx_{n_k}$ converges. But we also know that $(x_{n_k})$ is a bounded sequence, and $L$ is a compact operator. Hence there is a subsequence ...

Comment: @daniel Thanks. I work it out with yr hints given.:)